# How to restrict all outlook appointments (including recurring) by property value using C#

Tags: c#, outlook, outlook-addin

How to restrict all outlook appointments (including recurring) by property value using C#. I use
filter = "@SQL=(http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/string/{00020329-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}/TestName IS NOT NULL)" (where TestName - property name) and set calendarItems.IncludeRecurrences = true; but I get only simple appointments results

Answer (score 0):

To retrieve all Outlook appointment items from the folder that meets the predefined condition, you need to [sort](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff866960.aspx) the items in ascending order and set the [IncludeRecurrences](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff866969.aspx) to true. You will not catch recurrent appointments if you don’t do this before using the Restrict method.

```
    item = resultItems.GetFirst();
    do
    {
       if (item != null)
       {
           if (item is Outlook._AppointmentItem)
           {
               counter++;
               appItem = item as Outlook._AppointmentItem;
               strBuilder.AppendLine("#" + counter.ToString() +
                                     "\tStart: " + appItem.Start.ToString() +
                                     "\tSubject: " + appItem.Subject +
                                     "\tLocation: " + appItem.Location);
           }
           Marshal.ReleaseComObject(item);
           item = resultItems.GetNext();
       }
   }
   while (item != null);
```

You may find the following articles helpful:

- [How To: Use Restrict method in Outlook to get calendar items](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/11/15/outlook-restrict-calendar-items/)
- [How To: Retrieve Outlook calendar items using Find and FindNext methods](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/11/11/outlook-retrieve-calendar-items/)